# What a proof of weak convergence is supposed to look like

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Recall the definition of weak convergence: if $u_{k}\in \mathcal{B}$, we say that $u_{k}$ converges weakly to $u$ if $\forall \ell \in $ the dual space $\mathcal{B}^{*}$ ($\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space) implies that $\langle \ell, u_{k}\rangle \to \langle \ell, u\rangle$.

Now, for $u$ any fixed function in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ which is not identically 0, I need to show that the sequence of functions $u_{k}(x)=u(x+k)$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, but which does not converge in the usual sense.

The only problem is, I have absolutely no idea what this is supposed to look like - the only other problem I've ever seem like this was one where $u_{k}$ was an orthonormal basis for the space it was in, so that was ridiculously easy to show.

For that one, it basically involved something like showing that the sum of the inner product converged, and do that it's general term went to zero, but I'm not sure what that would look like in this case. If somebody would be willing to do this out in a detailed manner, just so I could see how a problem like this is supposed to be solved, I would appreciate it so very much!

Comment: $k \to 0$ or $k \to \infty$?

Comment: $k\to \infty$, gerw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some $M$ such that if $|x| > M$, then $u(x) = 0$. Also, there is some $B$ such that $|u(x)| \le B$ for all $x$. Hence
$|u(x)| \le  B \cdot 1_{[-M,M]}(x)$, and so
$|u_k(x)| \le  B \cdot 1_{[-M,M]}(x+k) =  B \cdot 1_{[-M-k,M-k]}(x)$.

The trick is to find a suitable representation for a member of the dual space, and this is furnished by the Riesz representation theorem.

If $\phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})^*$, then we can write $\phi(x) = \langle f, x \rangle$, for some $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and using the above  we get
\begin{eqnarray}
|\phi(u_k)| &=& | \langle f, u_k \rangle | \\
& \le & \int |f(x)|  |u_k(x)| dx \\ 
& = & \int |f(x)| 1_{[-M-k,M-k]}(x) |u_k(x)| dx \\ 
&\le& \|f \cdot 1_{[-M-k,M-k]} \| \|u_k\| \\
&=& \sqrt{\int_{ [-M-k,M-k]  } |f|^2 } (2MB)
\end{eqnarray}
Since $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we see that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt{\int_{ [-M-k,M-k]  } |f|^2 } = 0$, and so $u_k$ converges weakly to $0$.

Since $\|u_k\| = \|u\|$ for all $k$, then if $u \neq 0$, we see that the $u_k$ do not converge (if they did, then they would also converge weakly to the same limit).

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate your taking the time to go through that for me. I just have a couple of questions about what you did: 1) Is it a general property of elements of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ that the limits of their $L^{2}$ norms always go to zero?, and 2) Can you elaborate a little bit on the idea that since $||u_{k}||=||u||,\, \forall k$, then if $u\neq 0$, the $u_{k}$ do not converge? Thanks :)

Comment: (1) More generally, if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $\lim_{ k \to \infty} \int_{|x|>k} |f| = 0$. You can see this by using the dominated convergence theorem on the functions $f \cdot 1_{\{x| |x| >k\}}$. (2) Suppose $u_k \to \hat{u}$, then we must have $u_k$ converging to $\hat{u}$ weakly as well. In this case, since $\|u_k\| = \|u\| \neq 0$, then if they did converge to some $\hat{u}$, we would have $\phi(u_k) \to \phi(\hat{u})$ for any $\phi$. We could choose some $\phi$ such that $\phi(\hat{u}) \neq 0$, which would contradict the result above. Hence the $u_k$ do not converge.

Comment: Thank you; that helps a lot!

Comment: Actually, the second part of your comment helps a lot, but the more I think about the first part, the less convinced I am. It seems that the integral you're using dominated convergence on is the integral over the complement of $[-M-k, M-k]$...

Comment: The interval is contained in $(-\infty, M-k]$ and as $k\to \infty$, the $\sup$ of this set 'goes' to $-\infty$, and for any integrable $f$, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{(-\infty,M-k]} |f| = 0$.

Comment: Because, in limit, you're integrating over an interval of length zero?

Comment: Well, that's one way to look at it. You can take $f_k(x) = f(x) 1_{(-\infty, M-k]}(x)$ and note that $|f_k| \le |f|$ and also $f_k(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, hence the dominated convergence theorem gives the desired result.

Comment: This is my take to why $u_{k}$ does not converge in the usual sense. What do you think?: if $u_{k}$ were convergent in the usual sense, we would need to have $u_{k}$ converge to the same limit, $0$, that it converges to weakly. So, we would need $\lim_{k \to \infty}||u_{k}-0||=0\, \to \, \lim_{k \to \infty}||u_{k}||=0$, and since $||u_{k}||=||u||$, this would imply that $\lim_{k \to \infty}||u||=0$, and since $||u_{k}||=||u||$, this would imply that $\lim_{k \to \infty}||u||=0$, which we cannot have, since $u$ is not identically zero.

Comment: Yes, that works (see (2) in my comment above).

Answer (score 2):

If $u\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $n=n(\varepsilon)>0$, such that
$$
\int_{|x|>n}|u|^2\,dx<\varepsilon^2.
$$ 
Why? Because, the function
$$
u_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
u(x) &\ \text{if} & |x|\le n, \\
0 &\ \text{if} & |x|> n,
\end{array}\right.
$$
converges pointwise to $u$, and $\int_{\mathbb R}|u_n|^2\le\int_{\mathbb R}|u|^2$, and using
Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we obtain that 
$$
\int_{|x|> n}|u(x)|^2\,dx=\|u_n-u\|^2<\varepsilon^2,
$$
and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|u_n-u\|=0$.

So, if $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and supp$\,\varphi\subset [-N,N]$, and $k>N+n(\varepsilon)$, then
\begin{align}
(u_k,\varphi)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_k(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx=\int_{-N}^N u(x+k)\,\varphi(x)\,dx=\int_{-N+k}^{N+k} u(x)\,\varphi(x-k)\,dx,
\end{align}
and hence
$$
|(u_k,\varphi)|\le \|\varphi\|\,\left(\int_{-N+k}^{N+k}u^2(x)\,dx\right)^{1/2}\le
\|\varphi\|\,\left(\int_{x>n(\varepsilon)}u^2(x)\,dx\right)^{1/2}\le
\varepsilon\,\|\varphi\|.
$$
This means that, $\lim_{k\to\infty}(u_k,\varphi)=0$, and thus $u_k\to u$ weakly. Not strongly though, as $\|u_k\|\not\to 0$.