# Weak Convergence Proof: Tried on My Own

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

This is related to a question asked here: [What a proof of weak convergence is supposed to look like](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662871/what-a-proof-of-weak-convergence-is-supposed-to-look-like)

I asked what a proof of weak convergence was "supposed to look like". Specifically, I asked that if $u$ was any fixed function in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ which is not identically $0$, then how would I show that the sequence of functions $u_{k}(x)=u(x+k)$ converged weakly to $0$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, but did not converge in the usual sense.

Since then, I decided to try my hand at showing that, for $u$ any fixed function in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$, $u_{k}(x)=k^{1/2}u(kx)$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, but not in the usual sense. The following is what I did. I was wondering, therefore, if somebody could look at it, and tell me whether it's right or not (and if not, what I need to do in order to fix it). I'm especially concerned about showing it doesn't converge in the usual sense, because I'm worried that the $k^{1/2}$ factor affects it in a way that I didn't take into account in my solution.

Here it is: since continuous functions with compact support are bounded, we have that $\exists B$ such that $|u(x)|\leq B = B \cdot \chi_{[-M,M]}$ $\forall x$. Therefore, $|u_{k}(x)|\leq B \cdot k^{1/2} \cdot \chi_{[-M,M]}(kx)=B \cdot k^{1/2} \cdot \chi_{[-\frac{M}{k}, \frac{M}{k}]}(x)$.

By the Riesz Representation Theorem, if $I \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})^{*}$, then $I(u)=\langle f, u \rangle$ for some $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

So, $|I(u_{k})|=|\langle f, u_{k} \rangle | \leq \int |f(x)||u_{k}(x)|dx \leq \int |f(x)|\chi_{[-\frac{M}{k}, \frac{M}{k}]}(x)|u_{k}(x)|dx$. Then, applying Holder's inequality, we get that this is

$\leq ||f(x)\cdot \chi_{[-\frac{M}{k}, \frac{M}{k}]}||\,||u_{k}|| \leq ||f(x)\cdot \chi_{[-\frac{M}{k}, \frac{M}{k}]}||\,B\cdot k^{1/2} \cdot [\frac{M}{k}-\left(-\frac{M}{k}\right)]$
$= ||f(x)\cdot \chi_{[-\frac{M}{k}, \frac{M}{k}]}|| \frac{2MB}{k^{1/2}}$.

Now, as $k \to \infty$, $|I(u_{k})|\to 0$, which implies that $I(u_{k}) \to 0$, so $u_{k}$ weakly converges to $0$.

However, if $u_{k}$ were convergent in the usual sense as well, then it would need to converge to $0$ as well. So, we would need $\lim_{k \to \infty} ||u_{k}-0||=0$, which implies that $\lim_{k \to \infty}||u_{k}||=0$. And since $||u||=||u_{k}||$,  this would imply that $\lim_{k \to \infty}||u||=0$, which we cannot have, since $u$ is not identically zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine; the scaling factor $k^{1/2}$ is chosen exactly right to make the $L^2$ norm invariant under scaling.

Notational remark:  many people (myself included) denote by $C_0^\infty$  the class of smooth functions *with limit $0$ at infinity*, and by $C_c^\infty$ the class of smooth functions with compact support. From the context, I understand that you use $C_0^\infty$ for smooth functions with compact support; this is fine (and also common), but worth pointing out, due to this inconsistency of usage.

By the way, the assumption on $u$ can be relaxed to just $u\in L^2$. Indeed,  for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $M$ such that $\|u \chi_{\{|x|\ge M\}}\|_{L^2}\leq \epsilon$. Following your computations, $\int |f u_k|$ can be shown to be at most $$2MB k^{-1/2}\|f\chi_{[-M/k,M/k]}\|_{L^2}+\epsilon \|f\|_{L^2} $$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $I(u_k)\to 0$.